# STL for Fibonacci Heap?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, fibonacci-heap

where is the Fibonacci Heap in STL ?
and if STL do not implement Fibonacci Heap what is the best practice 
to implement it using existing algorithms and containers in STL ?

Comment: There's a C++ implementation in [Wikipedia](http://ideone.com/9jYnv) that seems pretty decent.

Comment: Probably because the STL was complex enough as it is, and it generally only provides the most used/needed functionality. As usual, however, boost has it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/heap.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[boost](http://www.boost.org) has [an implementation of it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/heap.html). Hope that helps. There doesn't seem to be one in the [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). Here's an example:

```
 for(int n=0;n<40;++n){
    std::cout<<"F("<<n<<")="<<fibonacci(n)<<std::endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there's not a Fibonacci heap in the standard library, I wrote an implementation.

It is used in a [paper that I wrote](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10034), where is then used with Dijkstra's algorithm. The full source code for that paper can be found [here](https://zenodo.org/record/7759164#.ZBrFkXbP29I).

```
//Struct used for each Fibonacci heap node
struct FibonacciNode {
    int degree; 
    FibonacciNode* parent; 
    FibonacciNode* child; 
    FibonacciNode* left; 
    FibonacciNode* right;
    bool mark; 
    int key; 
    int nodeIndex; 
};
//Fibonacci heap class
class FibonacciHeap {
    private:
    FibonacciNode* minNode;
    int numNodes;
    vector<FibonacciNode*> degTable;
    vector<FibonacciNode*> nodePtrs;
    public:
    FibonacciHeap(int n) {
        //Constructor function
        this->numNodes = 0;
        this->minNode = NULL;
        this->degTable = {};
        this->nodePtrs.resize(n);
    }
    ~FibonacciHeap() {
        //Destructor function
        this->numNodes = 0;
        this->minNode = NULL;
        this->degTable.clear();
        this->nodePtrs.clear();
    }
    int size() {
        //Number of nodes in the heap
        return this->numNodes;
    }
    bool empty() {
        //Is the heap empty?
        if (this->numNodes > 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
    void insert(int u, int key) {
        //Insert the vertex u with the specified key (value for L(u)) into the Fibonacci heap. O(1) operation
        this->nodePtrs[u] = new FibonacciNode;
        this->nodePtrs[u]->nodeIndex = u;
        FibonacciNode* node = this->nodePtrs[u];
        node->key = key;
        node->degree = 0;
        node->parent = NULL;
        node->child = NULL;
        node->left = node;
        node->right = node;
        node->mark = false;
        FibonacciNode* minN = this->minNode;
        if (minN != NULL) {
            FibonacciNode* minLeft = minN->left;
            minN->left = node;
            node->right = minN;
            node->left = minLeft;
            minLeft->right = node;
        }
        if (minN == NULL || minN->key > node->key) {
            this->minNode = node;
        }
        this->numNodes++;
    }
    FibonacciNode* extractMin() {
        //Extract the node with the minimum key from the heap. O(log n) operation, where n is the number of nodes in the heap
        FibonacciNode* minN = this->minNode;
        if (minN != NULL) {
            int deg = minN->degree;
            FibonacciNode* currChild = minN->child;
            FibonacciNode* remChild;
            for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++) {
                remChild = currChild;
                currChild = currChild->right;
                _existingToRoot(remChild);
            }
            _removeNodeFromRoot(minN);
            this->numNodes--;
            if (this->numNodes == 0) {
                this->minNode = NULL;
            }
            else {
                this->minNode = minN->right;
                FibonacciNode* minNLeft = minN->left;
                this->minNode->left = minNLeft;
                minNLeft->right = this->minNode;
                _consolidate();
            }
        }
        return minN;
    }
    void decreaseKey(int u, int newKey) {
        //Decrease the key of the node in the Fibonacci heap that has index u. O(1) operation
        FibonacciNode* node = this->nodePtrs[u];
        if (newKey > node->key) return;
        node->key = newKey;
        if (node->parent != NULL) {
            if (node->key < node->parent->key) {
                FibonacciNode* parentNode = node->parent;
                _cut(node);
                _cascadingCut(parentNode);
            }
        }
        if (node->key < this->minNode->key) {
            this->minNode = node;
        }
    }
    private:
    //The following are private functions used by the public methods above
    void _existingToRoot(FibonacciNode* newNode) {
        FibonacciNode* minN = this->minNode;
        newNode->parent = NULL;
        newNode->mark = false;
        if (minN != NULL) {
            FibonacciNode* minLeft = minN->left;
            minN->left = newNode;
            newNode->right = minN;
            newNode->left = minLeft;
            minLeft->right = newNode;
            if (minN->key > newNode->key) {
                this->minNode = newNode;
            }
        }
        else {
            this->minNode = newNode;
            newNode->right = newNode;
            newNode->left = newNode;
        }
    }
    void _removeNodeFromRoot(FibonacciNode* node) {
        if (node->right != node) {
            node->right->left = node->left;
            node->left->right = node->right;
        }
        if (node->parent != NULL) {
            if (node->parent->degree == 1) {
                node->parent->child = NULL;
            }
            else {
                node->parent->child = node->right;
            }
            node->parent->degree--;
        }
    }
    void _cut(FibonacciNode* node) {
        _removeNodeFromRoot(node);
        _existingToRoot(node);
    }
    void _addChild(FibonacciNode* parentNode, FibonacciNode* newChildNode) {
        if (parentNode->degree == 0) {
            parentNode->child = newChildNode;
            newChildNode->right = newChildNode;
            newChildNode->left = newChildNode;
            newChildNode->parent = parentNode;
        }
        else {
            FibonacciNode* child1 = parentNode->child;
            FibonacciNode* child1Left = child1->left;
            child1->left = newChildNode;
            newChildNode->right = child1;
            newChildNode->left = child1Left;
            child1Left->right = newChildNode;
        }
        newChildNode->parent = parentNode;
        parentNode->degree++;
    }
    void _cascadingCut(FibonacciNode* node) {
        FibonacciNode* parentNode = node->parent;
        if (parentNode != NULL) {
            if (node->mark == false) {
                node->mark = true;
            }
            else {
                _cut(node);
                _cascadingCut(parentNode);
            }
        }
    }
    void _link(FibonacciNode* highNode, FibonacciNode* lowNode) {
        _removeNodeFromRoot(highNode);
        _addChild(lowNode, highNode);
        highNode->mark = false;
    }
    void _consolidate() {
        int deg, rootCnt = 0;
        if (this->numNodes > 1) {
            this->degTable.clear();
            FibonacciNode* currNode = this->minNode;
            FibonacciNode* currDeg, * currConsolNode;
            FibonacciNode* temp = this->minNode, * itNode = this->minNode;
            do {
                rootCnt++;
                itNode = itNode->right;
            } while (itNode != temp);
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < rootCnt; cnt++) {
                currConsolNode = currNode;
                currNode = currNode->right;
                deg = currConsolNode->degree;
                while (true) {
                    while (deg >= int(this->degTable.size())) {
                        this->degTable.push_back(NULL);
                    }
                    if (this->degTable[deg] == NULL) {
                        this->degTable[deg] = currConsolNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        currDeg = this->degTable[deg];
                        if (currConsolNode->key > currDeg->key) {
                            swap(currConsolNode, currDeg);
                        }
                        if (currDeg == currConsolNode) break;
                        _link(currDeg, currConsolNode);
                        this->degTable[deg] = NULL;
                        deg++;
                    }
                }
            }
            this->minNode = NULL;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < this->degTable.size(); i++) {
                if (this->degTable[i] != NULL) {
                    _existingToRoot(this->degTable[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

no, there is no guaranteed fibonacci heap in the standard library

for an example of implementing a custom allocation scheme in C++, see the [small object allocator in the Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00632.html)

---

**EDIT**: sorry, i was thinking of the [fibonacci buddy system](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/f.html#fibonacci.buddies) for implementing a dynamic memory allocation heap.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is not stated explicitly as a Fibonacci heap, the STL implements a priority_queue which has the same complexity and the same api and behavior as a Fibonacci heap (and may actually be a Fibonacci heap in disguise)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is container adaptor which means that it takes another container (like `std::vector`) and provides new operations using that container in the background. It requires its container to provide random access iterator which means that it uses [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) in the background (theoreticaly it could use other heap implementation based on arrays). 
Bianary heap and Fibonacci heap don't have the same complexities. STL queue also has limited api compared to i.e. boost Fibonacci heap.